# Passing 2 arrays to a javascript function with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

This code submits a form and an ID # to addBand.php. The php inserts the form data into a DB, and then echos an array that houses 2 arrays: 1 is an array of ids, the other is a string to update an HTML select element. I've only included the PHP that generates and echos the arrays.

i keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectRestults' of undefined" with the following code. what am I doing wrong?

javascript/jquery:

```
      $(function() {

  $("#addBandForm").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var globalShowID = '&id=' + window.globalShowID;
   $.ajax({
     url: "womhScripts/addBand.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: $('#addBandForm').serialize() + globalShowID,
     success: function(msg) {

     var actArray = msg['actIDArray'];
     var bandArray = msg['bandSelectArray'];

     var result = bandArray['selectResults'];

     window.globalShowID='';

     $("#band1").html(result)

     },
     error:function(errMsg) {
       console.log(errMsg);
    }
   });
 });
});
```

addBand.php

```
$bandSelectArray = array();
$actIDArray = array();
$bandResults = "";

if (isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $ShowID = $_POST['id'];

    $actSQL = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT actID FROM Act WHERE showID=".$ShowID."");

    while($actRow = mysqli_fetch_array($actSQL))
    {
        $actIDArray[] = array(
            'actID' => $actRow['actID'],
         );     
    }
}


$selectBandSQL = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT bandID, bandName FROM Band");


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectBandSQL))
{

    $bandID = $row['bandID'];
    $bandName2 = $row['bandName'];

    $bandResults .= '<option value="'.$bandID.'">'.$bandName2.'</option>';   
}

$bandSelectArray['selectResults'] = $bandResults;



$resultArray = array();
$resultArray['actIDArray'] = $actIDArray;
$resultArray['bandSelectArray'] = $bandSelectArray;

echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: Try JSON.parse(msg) and convert it to an array in the success?

Comment: Try to console.log(bandArray) and paste result in question please

Comment: Then your AJAX response is incorrect

Comment: If using chrome - use "Log XMLHTTP requests"